# How can I get and append the table name to my query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on an access database, which has multiple tables with similar data. I am want to query the fields that are similar in addition to identifying which table each record came from.

This is what I have so far, I have multiple unions to append the field that is the same on multiple tables, but the part I am having trouble with is adding the column that would identify the table name.

Please help! Much appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_charger.[Object type] FROM SAP_charger 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_DME.[Object type] FROM SAP_DME
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_fiber_optic_repeater.[Object type] FROM SAP_fiber_optic_repeater
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_gateway.[Object type] FROM SAP_gateway 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_HMI.[Object type] FROM SAP_HMI 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_managed_switch.[Object type] FROM SAP_managed_switch
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_media_converter.[Object type] FROM SAP_media_converter
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_meter.[Object type] FROM SAP_meter 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_OLM.[Object type] FROM SAP_OLM 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_PLC.[Object type] FROM SAP_PLC 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_relay.[Object type] FROM SAP_relay 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_satellite_clock.[Object type] FROM SAP_satellite_clock 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_terminal_server.[Object type] FROM SAP_terminal_server 
INNER JOIN
SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE table_name in ( 'SAP_charger', 'SAP_DME', 'SAP_fiber_optic_repeater', 'SAP_gateway', ' SAP_HMI', 'SAP_managed_switch', 'SAP_media_converter', 'SAP_meter', 'SAP_OLM', 'SAP_PLC', 'SAP_relay', 'SAP_satellite_clock', 'SAP_terminal_server')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_charger.[Object type],'SAP_charger' FROM SAP_charger 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SAP_DME.[Object type],'SAP_DME' FROM SAP_DME
.....
```

Comment: so simple! can't believe I couldn't come up with that! Thanks a lot TGH!